# What does it mean that a blind person is "Patur" from mitzvot?

Tags: halacha-theory, reward-punishment, see-sight-vision-blind

When the Gemarah tells us that a Suma (a blind person) is "Patur" from Mitzvot, does that mean to say that he is completely outside the realm of Mitzvot, and will get no reward for doing them, or does it mean that while he has no obligation, he still gets some reward, possibly a Kiyum Mitzvah?

Comment: Interesting question. If you can provide examples of this contrast, it would make research easier. FWIW, I understand that despite that the Gemarah states that a Cheresh (deaf) is patur from all Mitzvot, I think Igeret Moshe claims that today they cannot use this as an excuse and MUST perform almost all mitzvoth except for those requiring hearing as being essential to the mitzvah. The main reason, here, is that today's cheresh is not the same as the one during the time of the Gemarah, and he has intelligence. And, IIRC, R. Moshe states that they receive reward for mitzvoth performed.

Comment: I don't know what it means to be "completely outside the realm of Mitzvot" FWIW. I do understand your question about reward though.

Comment: My understanding - In terms of literal definitions of the 2 terms, they appear to result in the same meaning. However, there appear to be subtle nuances. "Patur" seems to imply a "stronger" term, meaning he is "exempt". It seems to mean that he needn't even consider an attempt, because he is exempt from performing the mitzvah. "Eno Chayav", implies that he COULD consider performing the mitzvah, but he has no obligation to do so. As to what this means in terms of rewards or anything else, I don't know, offhand.

Comment: @DanF thanks for your interesting comments. What kind of examples(pertaining to your first comment) are you looking for?

Comment: women are also patur from many mitzvot. why should this be different?

Comment: @Bochur613 You alluded to (I assume, a mishna) that uses the term, "patur", but did not give an example of the use "Aino Chayav". I'm suggesting that if you can cite examples of both in your question, it would assist in formulating an answer. More than 1 example of each, might be better, to see if there is a consistent pattern, as I hope there would be. I may relay your question to dinonline.org. This type of question is probably "up their alley".

Comment: @DoubleAA lechoira he means שאינו בתורת

Comment: Why does being exempt mean that reward is not received? One who does but is not commanded is termed "wino metzuvah v'oseh" and generally receives reward; albeit less than one who is commanded.

Comment: _Eino Chayav_ sounds to me like a _din_ after the fact. For example, if someone eats less than a כותבת הגסה on _Yom Kippur_ he is **not _chayav_** _karet_, but that doesn't mean that he is **_patur_** from fasting.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara states about R` Yosef who was blind that he wondered whether he got more reward because he was blind and therefore non-obligated and did them anyways or less reward because he was non-obligated and so doing them was easier. Like when mom asks you to clean your room you don't want to but a day later you decide on your own that you want a clean room. What changed? You weren't being forced so it is easier.

I believe the Gemara's conclusion is that they receive less reward for the fulfillment. However, I have heard that since they are non-obligated, many times it's more meaningful to blind people so they would be fulfilling the imperative *Rachamana liba bouy* Hashem wants the heart.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question _Is there a difference between “Patur” and “Eino Chayiv”_

Comment: @DannySchoemann But it does address the question body which AFAICT doesn't match the question title.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara in Bava Kamma 87a indicates that a blind man is still within the realm of mitzvot and merits the reward of one for whom the mitzvah is optional rather than obligatory (*mi she'eino metzuva v'oseh*):

> אמר רב יוסף מריש הוה אמינא מאן דאמר הלכה כר' יהודה דאמר סומא פטור מן
>   המצות קא עבדינא יומא טבא לרבנן. מאי טעמא? דלא מפקדינא וקא עבדינא
>   מצוות. השתא דשמעית להא דר' חנינא דאמר ר' חנינא גדול המצווה ועושה ממי
>   שאינו מצווה ועושה, מאן דאמר לי: אין הלכה כרבי יהודה עבדינא יומא טבא
>   לרבנן. מאי טעמא? דכי מפקדינא אית לי אגרא ***טפי***.
>
> Rav Yosef (who was blind) said: Originally, I would say that if one
>   says the halacha is like Rabbi Yehuda who said that a blind person is
>   exempt from the commandments, I will make a holiday for our rabbis.
>   Why? For I'm not commanded yet keep the *mitzvot*. Now that I heard
>   that which Rabbi Chanina said - for Rabbi Chanina said that one who is
>   commanded and does is greater than one who is not commanded and does -
>   if one says to me the halacha is *not* according to Rabbi Yehuda, I'll
>   make a holiday for our rabbis. Why? Because if I'm commanded, I have
>   ***even more*** reward.

(The clear implication is that even if we say a blind man is "patur", he still receives reward and is included in the mitzvot, just not the same level of reward as one who is "metzuvah" - obligated.)

Comment: Isn't this the same as the existing answer?